# passing a "where condition" to jasperreports exporting pdf

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

A simple SQL table, with two attributes and three rows:

> reference     | name:
>
> 0 |    first
>
> 1 |            second
>
> 2  |           third

I have a Java application, with Swing, showing this through a JList (each row concatenates the two strings, reference and name).

I push a button, I export the entire database successfully, using my "from_ireport.jasper", compiled from iReport. I can compile from code too.

I want to select one or more elements, push the button and get a pdf with just the selected elements. Where and how do I specify the "where condition" to jasper?

I can't find a easy example to look at.
Thanks.

Comment: @MarkGreen If you are using ***queryString*** (with SQL query) you can use parameter for passing *WHERE condition*. You can look at this [Query Sample](http://jasperforge.org/uploads/publish/jasperreportswebsite/trunk/sample.reference/query/index.html#query) for more details

Comment: That example is great, finally I understand how to create dynamic queries. You should put your comment as an answer, so I can vote.

Comment: Vyccus, I passed a Hashmap, but I didn't know why. The fillReport() method needed that, but I didn't notice changes (I didn't know how to use that). Now I understand.

Comment: Yeah, this hash is used to pass parameters when you need them, but as I can see you are using query then I'm not able to help you with that. Sorry

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For solving this issue you can use the *JR* report's parameters.

For example you can use this query expression:

```xml
<queryString>
        <![CDATA[SELECT reference, name FROM table WHERE $P!{whereCondition}]]>
</queryString>
```

The sample of Java code for passing parameter's value:

```java
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("whereCondition", "reference > 0");
JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(reportSource);
JasperPrint jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, params, connection);
```

---

For more details you can view [Query Sample](http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/sample.reference/query/index.html#query).